# Reshape an array in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I have an NumPy array of size `100x32` that I would like to reshape it to `10x10x32`. Therefore, the first 10 rows to be the first element of the new matrix 1x10x32, the next 10 rows to be the second element and so on. I tried to use reshape, however, I am not sure if it is quite a smooth solution, for example I did the following:

```
pred = pred.reshape(10, 10, 32) # pred initial is of size 100x32
```

Does that code do what I want properly?

Comment: "Does that code do what I want properly?".  *Does it?* Have you run the code and checked if the output is what you are expecting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should work. If you have the following.

```
x = np.arange(3200).reshape(100, 32)
```

Then

```
x.reshape(10, 10, 32)

print(x.shape)
# (10, 10, 32)
```

should work, assuming your numpy array has the correct shape. This assumes that `x.size = 3200`.